# ExtJs4: loading json data into a grid

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

i've seen there are many question about this argument but anyone has an answer that fits for me. So let's dig into the code:

```
Ext.define('Platform Member', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
       {name: 'id'},
       {name: 'name',      type: 'string', convert: null,     defaultValue: undefined},
       {name: 'email',     type: 'string', convert: null,     defaultValue: undefined},
    ],
    idProperty: 'id'
});
```

This is the grid, it is recognized and the grids are in the webpage.

```
 var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
     autoLoad: true,
     model: "Platform Member",
     proxy: {
         type: 'ajax',
         url: '../static/platform-member.json',
         reader: {
             type: 'json',
             root: 'response/platform_members'
         }
     }
});
```

Question, is the root attribute the node of the json three which should be read? Cause the names of the grid's columns are the names of the fields of this node that should be read in the json file. The json file is below but i suggest you to read with this [viewer](http://www.jsonviewer.stack.hu/).

The [json](http://pastebin.mozilla.org/3025096).

Agnese

Comment: Why only post half of the information? What does the JSON response look like. What is your grid configuration? Why did you declare name and email to be `float`?!?!

Comment: You're right, i'm fixing it..

Comment: Fixed the problems. Thank you Evan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, the root is incorrect. It should be `response.platform_members`.

Also, the model name is a class name, so it should be `PlatformMember`.

Comment: Thank you, i'm new to Ext.js so your answer was helpful for me.